# O(log n) algorithm in theory runs much slower in practice

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

The algorithm is for calculating 2^n recursively. I have used the Master theorem to determine that the time complexity is indeed O(log n) which seems to correct according to other sources online.

```
def pow(n):
    """Return 2**n, where n is a nonnegative integer."""
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    x = pow(n//2)
    if n%2 == 0:
        return x*x
    return 2*x*x
```

My problem is that it does not run in logarithmic time when i measure it in python for many and largevalues of n. Instead, it seems to be running at something like O(n) or even O(n*logn) time. Is this because of the large multiplication in the return statements or something else? If so, can the algortithm even be considerd O(log n) if that is not what determines the final outcome in terms of speed?

Comment: The algorithm does O(log n) multiplications. If the time for a multiplication is O(1), then the algorithm is O(log n). But you can't multiply arbitrary-length numbers in O(1), so you have to take the time to multiply into account.

Comment: Most languages have fixed-size integers, so the time complexity of all arithmetic operations is O(1). But a few languages (e.g. Python, Common Lisp, Scheme) have unbounded integer representations. If your inputs aren't constrained, this makes addition/subtraction O(n), and multiplication/division O(n^2).

Comment: @Barmar I think there is a bit of confusion there. The question and rici's comment both call `n` the number represented by the input. The complexity of function `pow` defined in the function is O(log(n)) where n is the number. The complexity of addition is O(n) where n is *the size of the input*. You're calling two different quantities by the same name n. If you call `k` the size of the input and `n` the number represented by the input, then k ≈ log(n), so addition is O(k) or equivalently, O(log(n)), and multiplication is O(k²) or equivalently, O(log(n)²).

Comment: @Stef Complexity can be dependent on multiple inputs. So the correct thing would be to say it's O(n * m^2), where n is the number of inputs, and m is the maximum size of the input items.

Comment: @Barmar `n` is not the number of inputs. It's literally the number that is inputted. Don't reuse the same name for two distinct quantities. You might know what you're talking about, but the asker isn't, and calling everything `n` is confusing for no reason!

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is O(log n) assuming each of the numbers fits in one word of memory. That assumption doesn’t hold if the sizes of the numbers increase.